# Weird characters in output file

Tags: linux, character-encoding

I opened the output file created from a script in my terminal and the output file is fine, shows the output i want.

```
cat 2_val.txt
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
```

When i open it using Notepad, why the output file shows weird characters?

```
2_val.txt
਱਱਱਱਱਱਱਱਱਱ਲਲਲਲਲਲਲਲਲਲਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼ਲ਼਴਴਴਴਴਴਴਴਴਴ਵਵਵਵਵਵਵਵਵਵ
```

Is there something wrong with file's charset? How can i fix this?

Comment: Look at `file 2_val.txt`. Look at `od -bc 2_val.txt`.

Comment: It looks like your notepad assumes the text file is encoded in UCS-2LE. Why it does that you may need to ask on some Windows forum.